# Accepting certain answers

Tags: python, variables, conditional-statements

I am writing a script in python which asks a user to enter their Hogwarts house. This is then saved to a variable. How do I create a condition check to make sure they have entered a valid house?

Comment: could you provide some code as to what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

Say you have the code:

```
houses = ["Slytherin", "Gryffindor", "Hufflepuff", "Ravenclaw"]
inp = raw_input("What house are you in? ")

if inp in houses:
    print("Valid house!")
else:
    print("Invalid house!")
```

Sample output:

> What house are you in? Slytherin
>   Valid house!
>
> What house are you in? a
>   Invalid house!

To run in a loop:

```
houses = ["Slytherin", "Gryffindor", "Hufflepuff", "Ravenclaw"]
valid = False

while not valid:
    inp = raw_input("What house are you in? ")
    if inp in houses:
        print("Valid house!")
        valid = True
    else:
        print("Invalid house!")
```

Comment: Could you do this using a while loop so it will keep outputing 'Invalid house' until the user enters a valid answer?